# Creating an OMR-Based Website to Highlight All Sharp and Flat Notes in Sheet Music

Tags: python

I'm looking for an Optical Music Recognition (OMR) API that is compatible with Python and can process images of sheet music taken with an iPhone. The API should be able to accurately identify the pixelated position, pitch, and duration of each note. Additionally, it should provide the key signature for each line of music and updates to the key signature. I'm open to both paid and free options. Can you recommend an API that can reliably extract these variables?